# Laravel ajax search not working when I change the route

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, routes

I am currently facing issues with an ajax search, I think it has to do with the routes, but I'm not sure what is wrong. Maybe it's too early for coding.

**This works**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#name').on('keyup',function(){
    $value=$(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type : 'get',
        url : '{{ URL::to("/search") }}',
        data:{'name':$value},
        success:function(data){
            $('tbody').html(data);
        }
    });
})
</script>
```

**This does not work**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#name').on('keyup',function(){
    $value=$(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type : 'get',
        url : '{{ URL::to("/associates/search") }}', // Does not change if route name is used
        data:{'name':$value},
        success:function(data){
            $('tbody').html(data);
        }
    });
})
</script>
```

The routes are the following

```
Route::resource('associates', 'AssociateController');    

Route::get('/search','AssociateController@search');

Route::get('/associates/search', 'AssociateController@search')->name('associate.search');
```

The search method in the controller

```
public function search(Request $request)
{   
    if($request->ajax())
    {
        $output="";
        $associates=DB::table('associates')->where('name','LIKE','%'.$request->name.'%')->limit(10)->get();
        if($associates)
        {
            foreach ($associates as $key => $associate) {
                $output.='<tr>'.
                '<td>'.$associate->id.'</td>'.
                '<td>'.$associate->name.'</td>'.
                '</tr>';
            }
            return Response($output);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The route URI  `/associates/search` conflict with **resource** URI.

**Why?**

Because you created a **resource** route with URI `associates` :

```
Route::resource('associates', 'AssociateController');
```

This resource is reserved for :

```
Verb          Path                             Action  Route Name
GET           /associates                      index   associates.index
GET           /associates/create               create  associates.create
POST          /associates                      store   associates.store
GET           /associates/{associates}         show    associates.show
GET           /associates/{associates}/edit    edit    associates.edit
PUT|PATCH     /associates/{associates}         update  associates.update
DELETE        /associates/{associates}         destroy associates.destroy
```

That's why `/associates/search` conflict with that resource URI.

**How to solve?**

You need , just add a route to that method separately, **before** you register the resource:

```
Route::get('/associates/search', 'AssociateController@search')->name('associate.search');
Route::resource('associates', 'AssociateController');
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're already using named routes `->name('associate.search')`, try to get the route URL by its name:

```php
url: '{{ route("associate.search") }}',
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem even if it is a good suggestion.