# Laravel 8 custom routes return 404 while using resource

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-routing

The API endpoint `/clients/entries` returns a 404 error while using the route setup.

```
Route::apiResource('clients', ClientController::class);
Route::get('clients/entries', [ClientController::class , 'getAll']);
```

The endpoint only works when they are rearranged, so the resource route is at the end.

```
Route::get('clients/entries', [ClientController::class , 'getAll']);
Route::apiResource('clients', ClientController::class);
```

Why does this issue occur? And is it fine to have the resource route at the end?

Comment: Your second method is fine,  this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/62952620/15070659

Comment: @Espresso Thanks for the reference. Now I understand why it occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A full explanation can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/62952620/9004987 (thanks to @Espresso).

**Summary:**

When the resource route is registered at the beginning it will create some routes. Example:

```
GET   /clients/{client}   show   clients.show
```

And when other custom routes (such as `/clients/entries`) are registered after the resource route then it will conflict with the resource URI (since it has the same pattern).

**Solution:**

Define the custom routes before the resource route.

Answer (score -1):

Firs:
You need to direct requests from Routes/web.php to API

```
Route::get('/{any}', [App\Http\Controllers\ClientController::class, 'index'])->where('any','.*');
```

Requests from routes/api.php need to be answered